# Looking for a FTP solution on Linux with web-gui for administration

Tags: linux, ftp

I'm looking for a FTP solution which is running on Linux. It should be easily administrated by user. Means the user could be able to create user, manage their passwords and quotas etc. It would be nice if its a web-solution. What could you recommend?

Comment: If you change your mind about FTP and the web GUI, I recommend scp (a tool for ssh that lets you use it a lot like ftp) and/or sshfs, which lets you mount remote file systems (pretty easily).

Comment: Are you looking for a client, a server, or both?

Answer (score 0):

If you issue a package-management command like `apt` (for debian-based distributions) , and filter its output you'll get a long list of FTP Software which is available from the repositories. You can filter that for keywords like "server" or "daemon" to narrow down the list.

```
apt search ftp | grep -A 2 "server\|daemon"
```

The packages most likely  worth  a closer look are `tfdp`, `vsftpd` and `protfpd`.

It depends on your use-case. I don't know which of these has nice-looking web based admin tools. [Proftpd has one](https://mange.dynalias.org/linux/gproftpd), see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58635/gui-ftp-server-recommendation).
Remember this  can come from third parties (e.g. integrated in `webmin`, `cockpit` and the like).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Filezilla. I use it on both my Windows and Linux machines.

Comment: Welcome Fred!  Can you expand your answer to explain if it meets the questions requirements?  Thanks!